# Starting an agar.io like game. Tips on how to start

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

How to make a nice, simple version of agar.io? What kind of codes I should use?

Comment: Way too broad. You should ask specific problem here, not expect people to write code for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a tutorial site, nor a code-request site. And it's not a replacement for Google.

Comment: My tip for a complete beginner is to read the help pages anywhere you ask for help. It will help you get help.

Answer (score 0):

Start with learning HTML5.

[HTML5 tutorials](https://html5gameengine.com/tag/physics)